# Почему не закрывается prompt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prompt

Есть следующий код

```
jQuery('.close').on("click", function(){
    let tab_ID = prompt("Введите табельный номер");
    var tabID = this.getAttribute('data-tabid');
    if ((tabID != null) && (tab_ID == tabID)) {
        alert("Всьо чьотко!");
    } else {
        alert("Ну-ка, фраер, сдал назад, работа не твоя!");
    }
});
```

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку с классом "close", открывается окно prompt с полем ввода для табельного номера, после его ввода и нажатия на "ОК" выводит alert с соответствующим сообщением в зависимости от условий, но после нажатия "ОК" на алерте снова открывается prompt, а мне надо, чтобы оно закрылось, как это сделать?

Comment: В порядке бреда. В промп окошке кнопка Ок  не имеет ли случайно класса "close"? ))

Comment: @Quazimorda, Вы намекаете, что у кнопки **OK** в блоке с **prompt** есть класс **close**? или Вы так шутканули?

Comment: @Август, не намекаю, но это первое, что бы я проверил на месте автора вопроса. Потому что, если это так, то при нажатии на кнопку "Ок" в prompt, повторно будет срабатывать функция.

Comment: @Quazimorda, проблема в том, что даже если бы кнопка **OK** имела бы класс **close**, это бы ничего не изменило, так как во время загрузки `js` обработчик вешается на те элементы, которые есть в DOM **НА МОМЕНТ ОБЪЯВЛЕНИЯ ОБРАБОТЧИКА**. я только что проверил, что кнопки с классом `close` нет в документе. даже если она и появится (потом), обработчика на ней не будет

Comment: @Август, не буду спорить, но мне казалось, что вызов `$(selector).click(function(){...})` работает только если selector изначально есть в DOM, а вызов `$(selector).on("click", function(){...})` должен скушать и динамически созданные элементы, если selector совпадёт. А вот то, что такой кнопки нет - существенно.

Comment: @Quazimorda, аа.. ну я, откровенно, `jQuery` не знаю, так что Ваш вариант вполне возможен. искреннее прошу меня простить

Comment: @Август, ничего, я тоже могу ошибаться, но мы с вами дискутируем, а вот автор вопроса пропал. ))

Comment: @Quazimorda так само окошко промпт открывается при нажатии на кнопку с классом "close"

Comment: Во всплывающем окне у кнопки ОК разве класс close?)) Блин, а вдруг по умолчанию, сейчас класс попробую поменять

Comment: @Quazimorda не помогло, класс не влияет

Comment: @Август я уже заменил 
    
    $(selector).on("click", function(){...}) 
на 
    $(selector).click(function(){...})
не помогло

Comment: @Homie атрибут "data-tabid" у вас у кнопки с классом "close"?

Comment: @Quazimorda, разницы между `$(selector).click(function(){...})` и `$(selector).on("click", function(){...})` - нет

Comment: @Homie, добавь в вопрос [mcve] иначе нельзя догадаться что именно не так сработало

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле Вы не должны встречать подобной ошибки. 
Проверьте, нет ли у кнопки отдельного вызова `onclick`, где так же может присутствовать `prompt`, а так же полностью посмотрите, где дополнительно Вы можете вызвать обработчик нажатия кнопки или вызовов `prompt`.

Если разобрать код по составляющим, то 
При нажатии любой кнопки с классом `close` у Вас вызывается цепочка действий, в которой:
Вызывается `prompt` для ввода данных. После ввода и нажатия кнопки, данное окно закрывается.
Далее выполняется проверка и вызов алертов. В данном случае, точно никак не может вызываться ещё раз `prompt`, если Вы снова не нажимаете на одну из кнопок с классом `close`. 
Вам необходимо либо самостоятельно проверить весь код на вызов `prompt` в других местах, или убедиться, что нет другого способа вызова нажатия кнопки. 
Или выложите больше кода, чтобы мы смогли сказать Вам более подробно.

Вот пример вызовов нажатия кнопок с той последовательностью, что Вы указали:

```js
    jQuery('.close').on("click", function(){
        let tab_ID = prompt("Введите табельный номер");
        var tabID = this.getAttribute('data-tabid');
        if ((tabID != null) && (tab_ID == tabID)) {
            alert("Всьо чьотко!");
        } else {
            alert("Ну-ка, фраер, сдал назад, работа не твоя!");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-tabid="123" class="close">Закрыть</button>
<button data-tabid="222" class="close">Закрыть</button>
<button data-tabid="321" class="close">Закрыть</button>
```